# Loading contents of a Google Sheets cell into a PHP variable

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I'm attempting to load the contents of a single cell of Google Sheet into a PHP variable. From there I intend to make an image change on a website when the cell contents are changed to different values. I can't get the cell contents to load into a PHP variable to get this ball rolling though.

Google Sheets API gives the following PHP code to do this:

```
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
```

When I use this code after substituting my `spreadsheetId` and `range`, I `echo $result` and get nothing. I'm sure there's something I'm missing in the code or that the variables `$result` or `$service` need to be defined, but Google dropped the ball on the PHP side apparently. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When I run this with the spreadsheetId subbed in I get a t_string error. When I run this keeping $spreadsheetId intact and defining it earlier and setting it to the spreadsheetId Value, then I get Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object. I should mention this is in a wordpress site, if that has any bearing on it

Comment: "...or $service need to be defined".  Yes, `$service` obviously needs to be defined before you attempt to use it.  Are you not using the provided API library?  See https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/php

Comment: I'm sure I'm not. I'm trying to do this for a web page, So I assume I need to load JSON into the root directory of the site?

Comment: Somewhere accessible, yes.  Follow that guide, it pretty much walks you through it.

Comment: @steve could you share your code. I am not abel to retrive sheet data using server OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

download the V1 master (not master) from:
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=spreadsheets_values

copy on server, verify path of requires

put your code in an exemple, with the class declared for $service and variables $range, $spreadsheetId and $api_key (from explorer api of google, to auhenticate:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
)

run the modified exemple

PS: I look for multi-range in case you find the method with :

```
$range[]= 'Sheet1!A:C'; // I try to have all sheets in once
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
```